# Couchbase analytics: create index compilation error

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-analytics, couchbase-indexing

I'm trying to create an index on a couchbase analytics node:

```
CREATE INDEX `index_analytics_user_id` 
ON `requests`(userId:string)
```

When I run this on a couchbase I have running locally it works fine. However when I run it on the larger scale development environment (with multiple data and index nodes and a separate analytics node) I get an error.  Locally I run Couchbase 6.5.0. and the development environment runs Couchbase 6.0.2:

```
[
  {
    "code": 24001,
    "msg": "Compilation error: Dataset Default.requests is currently being fed into by the following active entities.\nDefault.Local.data(CouchbaseMetadataExtension)\n (in line 1, at column 1)",
    "query_from_user": "CREATE INDEX `index_analytics_user_id` \nON `requests`(userId:string)"
  }
]
```

How do I fix this?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Couchbase Analytics 6.0.x you need to manually stop data ingestion (disconnect the link) before issuing CREATE INDEX statement:

```
DISCONNECT LINK Local;
CREATE INDEX ...
CONNECT LINK Local;
```

For more information see
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/analytics/5_ddl.html#Connecting_and_disconnecting

In 6.5.0 this step is no longer necessary. The system automatically disconnects the link when processing CREATE INDEX and reconnects it after the index is built.

Comment:  Thanks. I asked this question of someone at Couchbase earlier and was told it was possible to add an index while the link was in place, but they must have been talking about CB6.5